# AD short name lookup errors after disabling 'append parent suffixes'

Tags: windows, active-directory

I manage an AD domain, let's call it "example.[local](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34981.best-practices-for-internal-ad-domain-and-network-names.aspx)". Its short netbios name is "EXAMPLE". The former shows up in reverse dns lookups and in AD configuration tools. The latter is seen whenever usernames and permissions are involved, like the welcome screen, which states that the logon domain is EXAMPLE and the currently chosen user is EXAMPLE\Administrator.

Tinkering, I went into Network Connections -> IPv4 -> Advanced -> DNS and unchecked the suboption `Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix` so that computers wouldn't make pointless queries to .local. Some PCs already had this option unchecked, so I concluded that either mode was fine. (Later I found that they go straight for LLMNR in both cases so it doesn't matter).

Afterwards, about half of the PCs would log AD domain lookup errors on startup (NETLOGON/5719, [GroupPolicy/1055](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc727272(v=ws.10).aspx), [Time-Service/129](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756526(v=ws.10).aspx)). Most of those PCs had to be rejoined to the domain to make the errors stop. They were probably transient, since everything still appeared to work correctly.

Does the above imply that all computers in a domain need to have that checkbox checked to avoid problems? Or did this happen because of some other misconfiguration somewhere? And why didn't this affect all computers consistently?
Is the short (netbios/legacy) name of the AD domain supposed to show up in the various parts of the Windows UI, and be used in name resolution? Would the Domain Functional Level affect this?

Comment: `Tinkering, I went into Network Connections -> IPv4 -> Advanced -> DNS and unchecked the suboption Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix so that computers wouldn't make pointless queries to .local. Some PCs already had this option unchecked, so I concluded that either mode was fine. (Later I found that they go straight for LLMNR in both cases so it doesn't matter).` - I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. What problem are you trying to solve? - `Is the short (netbios/legacy) name of the AD domain supposed to show up in the various parts of the Windows UI` - Yes.

Comment: Why do you consider the queries to .local "pointless"? That is what DNS is for.

Comment: This is a small network with a flat hierarchy. Nothing should be querying the parent domain because it doesn't really exist, and there is no authoritative dns server for that domain. I just got the idea to mess with that checkbox while fixing other, more broken stuff in that dns settings window.

I'm still hoping my analysis is incorrect, and that it doesn't really try to resolve the short domainname + devolved suffix, when the full suffix is readily available. Because that would make no sense.